# What is wrong with the dir variable and value

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
window.onload = function() {
   var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
   var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
   var t = Date.now();
   var x = 0;
   var y = 0;
   var dir = 1;
   var speed =  150 + Math.round(Math.random()*(75));
   
   x =+ 10;
  function draw() {
  
     var timePassed = (Date.now() - t) /1000;
         t = Date.now()
     context.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600)
     
      context.beginPath();
      context.rect(x, y, 100, 60)
      context.fillStyle = "white"
      context.fill();
    
   if (y <= 0) {
     dir = 2;
   }
   if (x <= 0) {
     dir = 1;
   }
    if (x>= 600-100) {
      dir= 2;
    }
    
    if (y >= 600-60) {
     dir = 3;
     }
    if  ((y >= 270 && y<= 300) && x >= 500) {
      dir = Math.round(Math.random()*4);
    }
     if ((x >= 250 && x <= 350) && y >= 540) {
       dir = Math.round(Math.random()*4);
     }
     if ((x >= 250 && x<=350) && y <= 0) {
       dir =Math.round(Math.random()*4);
     }
      if ( x >= 600-100 && y >= 300) {
     dir = Math.round(Math.random()*4);
   }
   if (x <= 0 && y>300) {
     dir = Math.round(Math.random()*4);
   }
   if (x >= 600-100 && y <= 300-60) {
     dir = Math.round(Math.random()*4);
   }
   if (x <= 0 && y <= 300-60) {
     dir = Math.round(Math.random()*4);
   }
   if (y <= 0 && x <= 300-100) {
     dir = Math.round(Math.random()*4);
   }
   if (y <= 0 && x >= 300) {
     dir = Math.round(Math.random()*4);
   }
   if (y >= 600-60 && x<=300-100) {
     dir = Math.round(Math.random()*4);
   }
   if (y >= 600-60 && x>=300) {
     dir = Math.round(Math.random()*4);
   }
      
      if (dir == 1) {
        x += speed*timePassed;
        y += speed*timePassed;
      }
      else if (dir == 2) {
        x -= speed*timePassed;
        y += speed*timePassed;
      }
      else if (dir == 3) {
        x -= speed*timePassed;
        y -= speed*timePassed;
      }
      else if (dir == 4) {
        x += speed*timePassed;
        y -= speed*timePassed;
      }
       
       
   if (speed > 225) {
        speed = 150 + (Math.round(Math.random()*75)); 
       }
     
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
     }
     draw();
}
```

I just wrote my first code to try and make a DVD screen saver animation kind of thing, but for some reason, my code keeps glitching on the corners;
Can you please help me fix it;
And please don't judge since it's my first code ever, and if you could fix it just by changing values and stuff and actually with the same logic, I used up there.

Comment: and where is the html part

Comment: Completely different note: don't use `window.onload` assignment. Use `<script src="yourfile.js" async defer></script>`, where the `async` attribute loads your script without blocking the page, and the `defer` makes the browser only runs your code once the document is ready for edits. We haven't needed window.onload or DOMContentLoaded since IE 10, which doesn't even exist anymore =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans you probably would't want use both `async` _and_ `defer` at the same time like that.

Comment: I'm not having a problem with the loading but i'm having problem with animation. Even though my object collides with the wall it keeps glitching into the wall

Comment: @Steerobrine Idk why you have so many conditions but if you just want to bounce back you can simply invert the part of the vector (dx, dy) depending on the side you hit.

Comment: @andy you absolutely would, because they do completely different things. You want to always load your scripts async because nothing should block your page load, and you want any code that interacts with the page to run deferred. The only note there is that if you're loading modern ESM using `type="module"`, your code already runs deferred by default and you don't need the `defer` attribute. But you _do_ still need the `async` attribute.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans except modern browsers will ignore `defer` if `async` is present, so you really need to know which one you want to use. Having both is redundant.

Comment: @andy That's going to need some proof linked in/added, because they regulate completely different parts of JS handling. One regulates the network behaviour while parsing the initial document, the other regulates the JS parser. There is zero sense in ignoring `defer` just because `async` is also used, they control completely different aspects of the page load process.

Comment: _"The async and defer attributes are boolean attributes that indicate how the script should be evaluated. Classic scripts may specify defer or async, but must not specify either unless the src attribute is present. Module scripts may specify the async attribute, but must not specify the defer attribute."_ - [HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#attr-script-async) - there is a note below where you _can_ use them both but only if you support legacy browsers. See also: [this handy summary](https://gist.github.com/jakub-g/385ee6b41085303a53ad92c7c8afd7a6).

Comment: That is not what the text you quote means at all. Modern JS (type="module") defers by default, and so browsers will ignore the defer _attribute_ if you add it. Legacy JS (type="javascript", or scripts left untyped, in which case the script element defaults to type="javascript") _will not_ ignore the defer attribute, and the text says that async and defer are only in effect when using sourced scripts (`<script src="..."></script>`), i.e. neither attribute does anything for inlined scripts (`<script>...</script>`).

Answer (score 2):

I reworked your logic a little and separated the calculation of horizontal and vertical speed:

```js
function rnd(n){return Math.ceil(Math.random()*n)}
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var t = Date.now();
const w=600,h=600;
var x = 10;
var y = 10;
var xspeed=150+rnd(75), yspeed=150+rnd(75);
function draw() { 
  var timePassed = (Date.now() - t) /1000;
  t = Date.now()
  context.clearRect(0, 0, w, h)
 
  context.beginPath();
  context.rect(x, y, 100, 60)
  context.fillStyle = "red"
  context.fill();

  if (y<=0 || y >= h-60) yspeed=-yspeed;
  if (x<=0 || x>= w-100) xspeed=-xspeed;
  x += xspeed*timePassed;
  y += yspeed*timePassed;
 
  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the HTML code it is difficult to give a correct answer.
The jacascript in general is running without console error
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/max951/pen/wvxMdom)

```
  <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600">
```

Randomly generating the direction with Math.round(Math.random()*4) can produce the behavior..

If the block has already moved out of the canvas in one direction, the random routine can still continue to produce exactly this direction and the block moves (or shakes) up and away :-)

Comment: It looks exactly like the one above

Comment: Yes you're right. 
But note, there is also HTML Code and you can see the "magic moving block".
And I edited my post to include my assessment of the cause.